# Query table based on input parameter

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have an input parameter to a query I'm trying to write.  Basically, `if mostRecentSnapshot == true` then I want to select only the most recent records from the process run (basically `where max(creationDate)`) and `if mostRecentSnapshot == false` then `select creationDate` and other columns normally.

To me, it makes sense to do this `if` statement in the `from` clause, but I don't think that's possible.  Normally I would use a CTE, but I those don't exist in MySQL.

What is the best way to achieve this?

It would be something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
CASE mostRecentSnapshot WHEN FALSE THEN 
(
processauditheader.creationDate as processCreationDate,
processauditheader.processName,
processauditheader.processType,
processauditheader.processHost,
processauditheader.processDatabase,
processauditheader.tableAudited,
processauditheader.processInvokedByName,
processauditheader.processInvokedByType,
processauditheader.processInvokedByDatabase,
processauditheader.processIntervalValue,
processauditheader.processIntervalField,
processauditheader.auditScenarios,
processaudititerationdetail.creationDate as iterationDate,
processaudititerationdetail.connectionId,
processaudititerationdetail.processDate,
processaudititerationdetail.tableRowCount,
processaudititerationdetail.tableRowCountLastDay,
processaudititerationdetail.previousProcessAuditIterationDetailID,
processauditmetricdetail.creationDate,
processauditmetricdetail.processAuditIterationDetailID,
processauditmetricdetail.auditMetric,
processauditmetricdetail.auditTotal,
processauditmetricdetail.auditExample
)
WHEN TRUE THEN 
(
((SELECT MAX(processaudititerationdetail.creationDate) as maxSnapshot,
processaudititerationdetail.id
from reporting_audit.processaudititerationdetail
group by processaudititerationdetail.creationDate) mostRecent

JOIN reporting_audit.processaudititerationdetail ON mostRecent.id = processaudititerationdetail.id)
)
END

FROM reporting_audit.processauditheader

JOIN processaudititerationdetail ON processaudititerationdetail.processAuditHeaderID = processauditheader.id
LEFT JOIN processauditmetricdetail ON processauditmetricdetail.processAuditIterationDetailID = processaudititerationdetail.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query can only return a fixed set of columns.  Perhaps the following does what you want:

```
select paid.*
from reporting_audit.processaudititerationdetail paid
where (not v_mostRecentSnapshot) or
      paid.creation_date = (select max(paid2.creationDate from reporting_audit.processaudititerationdetail paid2);
```

It will either select all records from the table or only the record(s) that have the most recent `creationDate`.

Comment: Here's what I came up with:
```select header.*, iteration.*, metric.*
from reporting_audit.processauditheader header
join processaudititerationdetail iteration on iteration.processAuditHeaderID = header.id
left join processauditmetricdetail metric on metric.processAuditIterationDetailID = iteration.id
where (not @mostRecentSnapshot) or
     iteration.processDate IN (select max(iteration2.processDate) from reporting_audit.processaudititerationdetail iteration2 GROUP BY iteration2.processAuditHeaderId)```